# Vue.js - push method for object throws Type Error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, typeerror

I am using push() method to add data to an object
and receiving an Error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.message.push is not a function

Some data is received from an API call, which is to be added to the object.

```
var price = new Vue({
        delimiters: ["[[","]]"],
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: {}
    },
    mounted () {
    {% for i in arr %}
        axios
        .get('https:apicall/symbol={{ x }}')
        .then(response => (this.message.push({name : response.data.price , cost: response.data.price.regularMarketPrice.fmt}))
    {% endfor %}
  }
})
```

However when I changed:

```
message: []
```

and

```
.then(response => (this.message.push(response.data.price))
```

it worked fine.

I am using Vue in Django framework and am new to Vue.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` is an array method not an object method, an array could be initialized as `message:[]` and an object like `message:{}`, so you could push a data to an array or assign that data to an object or a property inside that object like :

```
this.message=response.data.price
```

or

```
this.message.price=response.data.price
```